# Error PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php

I have 2 tables
one is category, other is jobs.

category table consist of 2 columns id and category
and table jobs have 3 columns id category_id and salary

The category_id tells the id number of category in category table ..
I want to count the number of rows whose category_id is 1 and then print the retrieved values...

**my php code**

```
$c_id=1;
$query=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE category_id = :cid');
$query->bindValue(':cid',  $c_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$result=$query->rowCount();
```

**Error**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE category_id=1' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\EsserePro\job1.php:281 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\EsserePro\job1.php(281): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown
```

Comment: Though it won't answer the original question you should do `SELECT COUNT(1) as c FROM jobs WHERE category_id = :cid` and get the result `$row["c"]` instead.

Comment: I want to print all the results and this is not working

Comment: in your question you said you wanted to count the number of rows, that's why I made that comment. You probably need to also mention that you intend to also print the results afterwards.

Comment: If you're using emulated prepares try disabling that in case MariaDB is objecting to it.

Comment: How can i disable ?

Comment: In your PDO constructor add `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false` in the array of parameters e.g. `$db = new PDO("connectString","user","pass",[ PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false ])`

Comment: Not working bro :(

Comment: In mysql client or phpMyAdmin, what does DESCRIBE jobs show you?

Comment: @rohitchakrabarti: Is the code we are seeing the actual code you have in your PHP script or have you changed it before adding it to stackoverflow? When you have changed it, can you please provider the correct current code? Also, for debugging purposes, write the SQL query in a variable and output it and check it syntax.